# React native navigation two title bars

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm not sure what is causing this, I followed the instructions to manually link RNNv2 and it works fine other than it containing a title bar with my app name that persists across every screen, as seen in this screen shot:

[image: twoTitles]

I am required to keep the MainActivity in my AndroidManifest file, just wondering if there is a way to hide this top blue persistent title bar?

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.stifirestop.fslocator">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
        android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
    <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
        android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
        android:resource="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.stifirestop.fslocator;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.rnziparchive.RNZipArchivePackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
import com.reactnativedocumentpicker.ReactNativeDocumentPicker;
import com.reactlibrary.RNReactNativeDocViewerPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.gettipsi.stripe.StripeReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.wix.RNCameraKit.RNCameraKitPackage;
import com.reactnative.photoview.PhotoViewPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  @Override
  protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
  ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, 
 isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };
 return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
}

@Override
public boolean isDebug() {
  return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}

protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
 // Add additional packages you require here
 // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
   return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
     new VectorIconsPackage(),
     new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
     new RNReactNativeDocViewerPackage(),
     new ReactNativeDocumentPicker(),
     new StripeReactPackage(),
     new RNCWebViewPackage(),
     new RNZipArchivePackage(),
     new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
     new RNFirebasePackage(),
     new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
     new RNCameraKitPackage(),
     new PhotoViewPackage(),
     new ImagePickerPackage()
   );
}

@Override
public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return getPackages();
}
```

}

I haven't added any RNN / react native JS code because this exact navigator works flawlessly on iOS, so I am assuming the issue must be with my Android code/RNN setup or implementation for android.

Comment: please provide code ….

Comment: @kinghenry can you please share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is android action bar please check android:theme tag into application tag in AndroidManifast.xml file

** android:theme="@style/AppTheme"**

Set NoActionBar theme in it change from style file
style.xml

```
<resources>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: thank you! i added a style.xml with these xml tags and changed the application tag xml property for theme to: android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" and it worked!

Comment: It's actually more about the `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` & `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` settings rather than the name of the style.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react native navigation you can do the following before you export the class component:

```
YourClassName.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: null,
})
```

Comment: This will  remove the portion of the header I want, the white part. Something is adding the blue portion and it’s not RNN not sure how to remove it